# Login php con sesion

Tags: php, login, sesiones

Estoy haciendo un login de acceso que guarde datos del usuario logueado que para un apartado web, me he basado en un ejemplo que he encontrado y tengo el problema que cuando recibo los datos de respuesta están en un array y no sé como asignarselos a la variable de sesion.

formulario login:

```
<!-- FORMULARIO LOGIN -->
                <form method="post" >
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <!--<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="mail" name="loginusuario" required>-->
                    <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername">Mail Usuario</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><span class="fas fa-user"></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="mail"  name="loginusuario" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <!--<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="mail" name="loginusuario" required>-->
                    <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername">Password</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><span class="fas fa-user"></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password"  name="loginpassword" required>
                    </div>
                </div>                          
                        <div class="row">
                            <?php
                                $login= new UsuarioControlador();
                                $login-> login();
                            ?>
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <button name="btnlogin" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Iniciar Sesión</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </form>
```

código controlador:

```
<?php
```

class UsuarioControlador{

```
public function login(){
   //echo "usuario: " . $_POST["loginusuario"];
   //echo "password: " . $_POST["loginpassword"];
   
    if(isset($_POST["loginpassword"]))
    {
        

        $usuario= $_POST["loginusuario"];
        $password= $_POST["loginpassword"];

        

        $respuesta = UsuarioModelo::mdlIniciarSesion($usuario,$password);
     
        if (count($respuesta)>0){
            
            //$_SESSION["usuario"]=$respuesta[0];
            $_SESSION["usuario"]='1';
            $_SESSION["nombreempleado"]='xxx';

            echo '<script>
                    window.location="xxxx"
            </script>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<script>alert("mal");</script>';
            
        }
    
    }
}
```

}

código modelo:

```
<?php

class UsuarioModelo{

static public function mdlIniciarSesion($usuario,$password){
    $conn=new PDO("mysql:dbname=xxx;host=xxx;charset=utf8mb4" ,"xxx","xxxx");
    
    
    $sql="Select * From Codificador_Empleados_new Where Usuario= '$usuario' and Pass= '$password'";
    
    $stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);
    
    
    $stmt->bindParam(":Usuario",$usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password",$password, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt-> execute();
    
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
   

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios problemas en tu código:

1. Tus consultas preparadas no son reales, porque no pones marcadores en la instrucción SQL.
2. Estás usando un método fetch para mapear los resultados a una clase, sin indicar qué clase es
3. No necesitas `fetchAll`, supongo que aquí esperas una sola fila

Corrigiendo lo antes dicho, el código quedaría así:

```
<?php

    class UsuarioModelo{
    
        public static function mdlIniciarSesion($usuario,$password){
            $conn=new PDO("mysql:dbname=xxx;host=xxx;charset=utf8mb4" ,"xxx","xxxx");            
            $sql="Select * From Codificador_Empleados_new Where Usuario= :usuario and Pass= :password LIMIT 1";           
            $stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);                        
            $stmt->bindParam(":usuario",$usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":password",$password, PDO::PARAM_STR);        
            $stmt-> execute();            
            return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);          
    }
}
```

Y donde llamas a este método:

```
    $respuesta = UsuarioModelo::mdlIniciarSesion($usuario,$password);
 
    if ($respuesta){  
        /*
           Aquí vamos a asumir que en la tabla
           hay una columna usuario y otra columna nombre
           por eso ponemos $respuesta["usuario"] y $respuesta["nombre"]
           de ser otros los nombres de columna
           cámbialos por los nombres reales
           No se ve en el código, de hecho, conviene que
           siempre escribas SELECT explícitos, indicando
           exactamente las columnas que quieres seleccionar
        */         
        $_SESSION["usuario"]=$respuesta["usuario"];
        $_SESSION["nombreempleado"]=$respuesta["nombre"];

        echo '<script>
                window.location="xxxxxxxx"
        </script>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script>alert("mal");</script>';
        
    }
```

Comment: he modificado mi código con tus anotaciones pero el error sigue siendo el mismo.

Comment: @JorgeSanz pon un `var_dump($respuesta);` justo antes de `if ($respuesta){` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: Lo primero de todo gracias por contestar!!
He modificado mi código con tus anotaciones pero sigue dando error.
si hago un dump_var($respuesta) veo que recibe el array con los valores. Pero cuando quiero asignarselo a la variable de sesion da error. El error exacto que me da es: "Undefined index: NombreEmpleado" y la tabla tiene ese campo, es mas lo veo cuando hago el dum_Var.

Comment: datos que muestra el var_dump
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Usuario"]=> string(16) "pedro" ["NombreEmpleado"]=> string(6) "pedro" } }

Comment: @JorgeSanz yo quisiera ver el resultado exacto del `var_dump`, para ver qué estructura tiene, lo puedes poner en la pregunta.

Comment: OK, parece que sigues usando `fetchAll`, pues los datos aparecen dentro de un array, usa `fetch`, como he sugerido en el código, o si dejas `fetchAll` debes meterte en el índice `0` del array.

Comment: Por otra parte, los nombres de clave de arrays son sensibles a mayúsculas/minúsculas, debes ponerlos tal y como aparecen, es decir, no es lo mismo `NombreEmpleado` que `nombreempleado`. Por favor, pulsa en editar y pon en la pregunta cómo tienes ahora el código, es evidente que has obviado algunas cosas y por eso no te está funcionando.

Comment: era el fetchtall, cambiado a fetch y sin problemas. gracias @A.cedano